# Script becomes unresponsive crashing firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this script cause an error on submit in firefox?
It is using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#errorMessage').hide();
    $('#form').submit(function() {

        var firstname = $('#formFirstname').val();

        if(firstname == '') {
            $('#errorMessage').html('Please enter your Name.');
            $('#errorMessage').fadeIn();
        }

        else {
            $('#errorMessage').html('Please wait a moment as the form Submits.');
            $('#form').submit();
        }
        return false;
    })
});
```

Comment: What is `formComp`? Also, you should probably `return true;` if you _are_ going to submit the form. Other than that, without the markup present, is this a form submission submitting a form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#form').submit();
```

causes recursion?

Comment: @Manual How would I prevent it from causing a recursive instance?

Comment: just return `false` when it should not submit. So don't return `false` by default en don't do the `$("form").submit()`

Answer (score 1):

You are aliasing the jQuery to `e`.

Change `$(document).ready(function(e) {` to `$(document).ready(function() {`

Or `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`

**Edit:**

Although it may not cause the error, in your code `e` is also `jQuery`'s alias, `e('#form')` will also work.

Comment: what do you mean I am aliasing JQuery to e?